# How to Create a Temporary Function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm making some tedious calls to a bunch of functions, but the parameters will be determined at runtime. I wrote a simple function to keep my code DRY but giving it a name is unnecessary. I don't use this function anywhere else.

I'm trying to do it the way I would in Scheme, but I get a `void-function` error:

```
(let ((do-work (lambda (x y z)
                  (do-x x)
                  (do-y y)
                  ;; etc
                  )))
  (cond (test-1 (do-work 'a 'b 'c))
        (test-2 (do-work 'i 'j 'k))))
```

I could stick it all into an `apply` (e.g., `(apply (lambda ...) (cond ...))`) but that isn't very readable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like other lisps (but not Scheme), Emacs Lisp has separate namespaces for variables and functions (i.e. it is a [‘Lisp<sub>2</sub>’, not a ‘Lisp<sub>1</sub>’](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace); see [Technical Issues of Separation in Function Cells and Value Cells](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html) for the origin and meaning of these terms).

You will need to use `funcall` or `apply` to call a lambda (or other function) that is stored in a variable.

```
(cond (test-1 (funcall do-work 'a 'b 'c))
      (test-2 (funcall do-work 'i 'j 'k))
```

Use `funcall` if you will always send the same number of arguments. Use `apply` if you need to be able to send a variable number of arguments.

The internal mechanism is that each symbol has [multiple “cells”](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html).
Which cell is used depends on [where the symbol is in an evaluated form](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Classifying-Lists.html).
When a symbol is the first element of an evaluated form, [its “function” cell is used](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html).
In any other position, [its “value” cell is used](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Forms.html).
In your code, `do-work` has the function in its value cell.
To access it as a function you use `funcall` or `apply`.
If it were in the function cell, you could call it directly by using its name as the car of an evaluated form.
You can accomplish this with [`flet` or `labels` from the *cl* package](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html).

Answer (score 21):

Do `(require 'cl)` to pull in the Common Lisp package, then use `flet` instead of `let`:

```
(flet ((do-work (x y z)
          (do-x x)
          (do-y y)
          ;; etc
          ))
  (cond (test-1 (do-work 'a 'b 'c))
        (test-2 (do-work 'i 'j 'k))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this the ANSI Common Lisp way (though I think there are some Emacs devels that will give you nasty looks):

```
(flet ((do-work (x y z)
                (do-x x)
                (do-y y)
                ;; etc
                ))
  (cond (test-1 (do-work 'a 'b 'c))
        (test-2 (do-work 'i 'j 'k))))
```

Dunno if you'll first have to `(require 'cl)` (or `cl-macs`?) to use flet.  If you want to define recursive functions you'll need to use `labels` IIRC.