# Elisp interactive function name

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to use the interactive function name feature. On emacs lisp manual it says:

‘a’
A function name (i.e., a symbol satisfying fboundp). Existing, Completion, Prompt.

So I tried it with a small test code:

```
(defun testfun1 ()
  (message "hello, world!"))

(defun test (abcd)
  (interactive "aTheme name: ")
  (abcd))
```

Emacs gives an error saying,

test: Symbol's function definition is void: abcd

I tried to test abcd with fboundp, it returns t. So I'm quite confused about how to use the 'a' option in interactive. 
Any body can give some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `test` receives its argument `abcd` as a function, but you can't just invoke a function by putting a symbol referencing it in the first position of a list to be evaluated. Since Emacs Lisp is a *Lisp-2*, the reference to the function provided to the interactive query is stored in symbol `abcd`'s *value slot*, not its *function slot*. The evaluation rules for a list like

```
(abcd)
```

involve looking in the first object's *function slot* if that object is a symbol, which it is in your case. If instead you wish to invoke a function referenced in a symbol's *value slot*, you need [the `funcall` function](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html):

```
(funcall abcd)
```

That says, "Take `abcd`, grab the value out of its *value slot*, and, provided it's a function, call it here, just as we would have if that function had been referenced in the list's first position either in a symbol's *function slot* or by a direct reference to the function object."

Here's [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657326/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-emacs-lisp/2657371#2657371) with references useful to allow you probe further.

Answer (score 0):

This should do this trick:

```
(defun test (abcd)
  (interactive "aTheme name: ")
  (call-interactively abcd))
```