# Why does my lisp code give me ...should be a lambda expression?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun helper-2 (list) 
  (if (null (first (rest list)))
      0)
  (+ (distance ((car list) (first (rest list)))) 
     (helper-2 (rest list))))
```

I'm new to lisp and I'm writing a program to compute the perimeter of any polygon with input following clockwise order. My logic is that I use a helper method to compute the length of two points next to each other and do the sum. After recursion is done, I will do a separate call to calculate the length from the beginning point to its end and sum everything up. I've finished the distance method which takes 2 points and return the length.

```
(distance '(2 0) '(4 0)) ;this will output 2
```

helper-2 logic:
     assume we have 3 points a (2 0) b (3 3) c (4 0) This method is expected to sum up the distance between ab and bc. However, I keep getting "(car head) should be a lambda expression" error. Can anyone help? Thank you. Or could anyone give me a better way to compute the perimeter of a polygon?

```
(defun square (n) (* n n))

(defun distance (a b)
  (let ((h (- (second b) (second a)))
        (w (- (first b) (first a))))
    (sqrt (+ (square h) (square w)))))
```

Comment: As an aside, you might want to keep your use of `first`/`rest` and `car`/`cdr` consistent, for readability's sake. Mixing `car` with `first`/`rest` here is a bit confusing. There's also `(cadr list)` which works the same as doing `(first (rest list))`.

Comment: In Scheme, `((car args1...) args2...)` would first evaluate `(car args1...)` to produce some value x and then tries to call x as a function with args2.  In Common Lisp, a function call has to be of the form `(xxx ...)` where xxx is either a symbol or a lambda expression `(car ...)` isn't either.  The implementation sees that's it's not a symbol, so figures that it should be a lambda expression, but it's not, and complains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `helper-2` function is wrong in two places:

1. You should be using a two-armed `if`, so that it functions as an if/else.
2. You have too many parentheses around the `(car list)`.

Here's the fixed version:

```
(defun helper-2 (list) 
  (if (null (first (rest list)))
      0
      (+ (distance (car list) (first (rest list))) 
         (helper-2 (rest list)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another question. How do I use this function? I've tried (helper-2 '(2 0) '(4 0)) it says too many arguments. How do I pass in a list of points?

Comment: It sounds like you should use `(helper-2 '((2 0) (4 0)))`? I have not tested it, though.

Comment: it says too few parameters for special operator if

Comment: You've actually modified the code from what I've got, and it's incorrect. Please cut and paste my code and use it directly.

Answer (score 4):

Section [3.1.2.1.2.3 Function Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm) of the HyperSpec describes how a form that is a cons, such as 
**((car list) (first (rest list)))**, is evaluated:

> How a compound form is processed depends on whether it is classified as a special form, a macro form, a function form, or a lambda form.

You can read the subsections linked to from that page for more details, but the essence is that since the first element of this list is not a symbol, the form as a whole must be a lambda form.  According to [3.1.2.1.2.4 Lambda Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababd.htm)  a lambda form is a list where the first element is a lambda expression.  `However, **(car list)** is *not* a lambda expression, so you get the corresponding error message.

You claimed that **(distance '(2 0) '(4 0))** will output two, but that shows **distance** being called with two arguments.  Even if **((car list) (first (rest list)))** could be evaluated, it would produce just one value, and so **(distance ((car list) (first (rest list))))** would call **distance** with just one argument. You should be doing this instead:

```
(distance (car list) (first (rest list)))
```

Also see:

- [Cannot use function call as first argument in s-exp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14204683/1281433)
- [Why do we need funcall in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9729549/1281433)
- [Do any lisps have a s-expression as their head, e.g. ((f 2) 3 4)? If not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12906945/1281433)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another question. How do I use this function? I've tried (helper-2 '(2 0) '(4 0)) it says too many arguments. How do I pass in a list of points?

Comment: @AnOverflowedStack I'm glad I didn't see this comment until now, since it appears you asked the same thing in a new question, [How do I pass in a list of list into a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26942585/1281433), in the meantime.