# How do I pass in a list of list into a function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun square (n) (* n n))

(defun distance (a b)
    (let ( 
        (h (- (second b) (second a)))
        (w (- (first b) (first a))))

        (sqrt (+ (square h) (square w)))
        )
)
(defun helper-2 (head) 
    (if (null (first (rest head))))
        0
    (+ 
        (distance (car head) (first (rest head))) 
            (helper-2 (rest head))
    )
```

I have this code written. My question is how do I use the helper-2 method? I've tried

```
(helper-2 '((2 0) (4 0)))
(helper-2 '(2 0) '(4 0)) neither works. Could anyone help? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please cut and paste the code in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941972/13) and use it verbatim. Here, you've actually made some changes to the code to make it incorrect: instead of your original one-armed `if`, you've made it even worse, a zero-armed `if`.

A correctly-formatted two-armed `if` expression looks like this (noting that `expr1` and `expr2` are supposed to be flush with (indented to the same level as) `test`):

```
(if test
    expr1
    expr2)
```

This means that if `test` evaluates to a truthy value (anything other than `nil`), then `expr1` is evaluated, and its value is the value of the `if` expression; otherwise `expr2` is used instead. In the code snippet I had, `test` is `(null (first (rest list)))`, `expr1` is `0`, and `expr2` is `(+ (distance (car list) (first (rest list))) (helper-2 (rest list)))`.

---

The other nice thing about using my code snippet directly is that it's already formatted correctly for [standard Lisp style](http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt), which makes it much more pleasant for other Lisp programmers to read.

Comment: Somehow it is all a matter of placing the wrong parens in the wrong places. I'm a CL newbie too, but not new at programming. To me, the editor turned out to be a good help in placing them at the right places.