# Recursive function in Emacs Lisp has void-variable error upon evaluating itself

Tags: emacs, recursion, elisp

I am trying to define a recursive function `balanced` that takes a string and returns true only if the parens in the string are balanced.

The elisp code I wrote is based on some Scala code I wrote for the Coursera class by Odersky, it's a transliteration.

```
  ;; check if expr (list of chars of some expression) is balanced
  (defun balanced (expr)
    (defvar lparen (string-to-char "("))
    (defvar rparen (string-to-char ")"))

    (defun is-open (c) (eq lparen c))
    (defun is-close (c) (eq rparen c))
    (defun is-empty (ls) (eq ls nil))
    (defun is-matching (l r) (and (is-open l) (is-close r)))

    (defun is-balanced (list stack)
      (cond ((is-empty list) (is-empty stack))

      ((is-open (car list))
       (is-balanced (cdr list) ;; 'push' open-paren onto stack
        (cons (car list) stack)))

      ((is-close (car list))

       (if (is-empty stack) nil
         (and 
          (is-balanced (cdr list) (cdr stack))
          (is-matching (car stack) (car list)))))

      (is-balanced (cdr list) (cdr stack))))
  is-balanced
```

I am in lisp-interaction-mode, so I used Ctrl-J to evaluate the above `defun` statement.

Then, when I attempt to evaluate this:

```
  (balanced "(balanced nil nil)")
```

I get a void-variable error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable is-balanced)
    balanced("(balanced nil nil)")
    (progn (balanced "(balanced nil nil)"))
    eval((progn (balanced "(balanced nil nil)")) t)
    eval-last-sexp-1(t)
    eval-last-sexp(t)
    eval-print-last-sexp()
    call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
    recursive-edit()
    debug(error (void-variable is-balanced))
    balanced("(balanced nil nil)")
    (progn (balanced "(balanced nil nil)"))
    eval((progn (balanced "(balanced nil nil)")) t)
    eval-last-sexp-1(t)
    eval-last-sexp(t)
    eval-print-last-sexp()
    call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
    recursive-edit()
```

The function doesn't seem to recognize itself, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the by, it doesn't make much sense to use `defvar` and `defun` inside a `defun`.  The former in particular is not doing what you think.  You probably want to use `(let ((lparen ...) ...) ...)` if the intent is to introduce a local variable.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, I will use `let` for local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute your function `(balanced ...)`, what it does is this:

1. It first defines two global variables
2. It defines five other functions
3. It accesses the variable `is-balanced`.

Step 3. happens right after the end of `(defun is-balanced (list stack) ... ))))`.

```lisp
(defun balanced (expr)
    ...

    (defun is-balanced (list stack)
      ...
      (is-balanced (cdr list) (cdr stack))))
  is-balanced ;; <= here!
```

But you have not defined such a variable. You have defined a *function* of the same name, but you cannot access function objects as if they're variables in Emacs Lisp. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657371/261142). Since there is no variable named `is-balanced` you get an error message.

(That said, there's a lot to be critized about the rest of your code. For starters, be aware that by having `defun`s inside `defun`s, you're re-defining your `is-*` functions *every single time* you're invoking `(balanced ...)`. That's certainly not what you want. Similarly, you probably want to move the defvar outside the function body, since they define *global* variables. Or did you mean to use `(let ...)` instead? If you really want global values, then `(defconst...)` might be more appropriate.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the final element of the `cond` expression is not wrapped in `(t` ... `)`:

Incorrect:

```
    (is-balanced (cdr list) (cdr stack))
```

Correct

```
    (t (is-balanced (cdr list) (cdr stack)))
```

The reason this is needed is that the last expression is supposed to be the `else` case.